# C++ one dimensional array of pointers

Tags: c++

I would love to know how I can insert data to an array of pointers:

```
//this is the array
Int **array
```

My usage should not be a two dimensional manner

So I wanna do something like:

```
Array=new int *[5];
Array[0]=2;
```

Comment: Better use a `std::vector` instead of a raw array.

Comment: `Array=new int *[5];` should be `Array=new int [5];`. But formatting, and actually being clearer about the question might help. And consider `vectors` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int* array = new int[10]; // array
array[0] = 15;            // set 15 to first element of array
delete []array;           // free allocated memory
```

You have to allocate memory for `array`. then you can access elements using [].

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** want an array of pointers you have to insert pointers, not ints.

```
//this is the array
int **array
array=new int *[5];
array[0]=new int{2};
```